# UITextField animate input view frame animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, inputview

I am developing an application that displays a custom Keyboard (similar to Messenger's) (containing images).
I have been asked to add a button that changes the frame of the keyboard with an animation. But when i set the frame it does not change at all.
Is this possible to do ? Could this be done nicely or do i need some work around ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inputView Property Of TextField,

```
UITextField *textFieldWithCustomView;
UIView *customView;
[textFieldWithCustomView setInputView:customView];
```

and when you want to expand/Collapse use

```
- (void)toggleCustomView:(BOOL)expand
{
    if (expand) {
        [textFieldWithCustomView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [textFieldWithCustomView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

When you want to show key board use

```
[self toggleCustomView:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry i think i did not make my self clear. When saying "Expand/Collapse" i did not mean "Hide/Show" but i meant changing the frame of the custom keyboard. I have been asked to add a feature that allows to change the size of the keyboard with an animation. Lets suppose the custom keyboard have an initial size (320, 216). When i tap the button, the keyboard size should change (animated) to (320, 400). And when i tap the button again, the frame should return to its initial value.